# Loop through object's keys, then loop through values (because they are arrays)

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```js
const example = {
  first: [*arrays objects*],
  second: [*arrays objects*],
  third: [*arrays objects*]
}
```

So, the situation is this: the example has 3 keys. Each key has an array of objects. First i want to loop through the objects keys (first, second, third), then the array of them (with forEach). How can i do that?

Comment: You should check out MDN, a truly great JavaScript reference. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop an object you need to specify what are you looping, in this case i use the keys

```
 Object.keys(example).forEach()
```

Hope this helps :>

```js
const example = {
  first: [{object: '1'},{object: '2'}],
  second: [{object: '3'},{object: '4'}]
}


Object.keys(example).forEach( entrie => {
  console.log(entrie)
  example[entrie].forEach(object => {
    console.log(object)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys( object ) will give you the keys of an object as an array.

```
const example = ...
Object.keys( example ).forEach( ( key, index ) => {
    example[key]; // This is your array you wish to loop through.
});
```